# Lowercase JavaScript object values

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array of JavaScript objects:

```
var obj = [{key1: Value1, key2: VALUE2},{key1: Value1, key2: VALUE2}];
```

I want the value of the key2 to be in lowercase, like this:

```
var obj = [{key1: Value1, key2: value2},{key1: Value1, key2: value2}];
```

How can I change the value from lowercase to uppercase?

Comment: You can't change the name of variables and expect it to work

Comment: Are the values quoted? Or are they any other variable?

Comment: If it's a string, you can use `.toLowercase()`

Comment: Your title is saying uppercase but your question is saying lowercase. You should choose one maybe..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to change the value of each object's `key2` property, to be a lowercase string (I'm assuming they're strings).

You can do this with a simple map.

```
obj = obj.map(function(a) {
    a.key2 = a.key2.toLowerCase();
    return a;
});
```

There are some differences in all the answers given here, surrounding object references. In my answer above, the array itself will be a new reference, but the objects inside will remain as the same reference. To clarify this by way of example

```
var mapped = obj.map(function(a) {
    a.key2 = a.key2.toLowerCase();
    return a;
});

console.log(obj === mapped) // false
console.log(obj[0] === mapped[0]) // true
```

If you're using a `for` loop or a `forEach` array function, then the array reference will remain the same.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pev7L89r) for reference.

Comment: this will loop through all the values, so lets say you have an Array with 20 values it will update the key2 20 times.

Comment: @RobinKnaapen That's the idea yes. For instance, in the example he has two values in the array, they both need to be updated as per his output example.

Comment: oops, it's so early for me.. i didn't notice it was a multi dimensional object... my fault

Comment: Good job explaining the difference between `for` `forEach ` and `assign`

Comment: If you use `Object.assign` the first argument will be the reference that is returned. So if you pass `item` to it, the reference will *not* change. Only if you call `Object.assign({}, item, { key2: item.key2.toLowerCase() })`, a new object will be created.

Answer (score 2):

```
caseInsensitivity = function(obj) {

    Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => {

        if(typeof obj[k] == 'string') {

                obj[k] = obj[k].toLowerCase();
        }
        else if(typeof obj[k] == 'object') {

            caseInsensitivity(obj[k]);
        }
        else {

        }
    });
    return obj;
}
```

To convert all values even if the values are nested objects or arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate the array and the keys, you want to change, and assign the lowercase value if you have a string.

```js
var array = [{ key1: 'Value1', key2: 'value2' }, { key1: 'Value1', key2: 'value2' }];

array.forEach(function (a) {
    ['key2'].forEach(function (k) {
        if (typeof a[k] === 'string') {
            a[k] = a[k].toLowerCase();
        }
    });
});

console.log(array);
```

A version with a fixed key.

```js
var array = [{ key1: 'Value1', key2: 'value2' }, { key1: 'Value1', key2: 'value2' }];

array.forEach(function (a) {
    if (typeof a.key2 === 'string') {
        a.key2 = a.key2.toLowerCase();
    }
});

console.log(array);
```

Comment: that would make all strings lowercase, not just `key2`

Answer (score 1):

You can use built-in array functions like forEach or map

```
// in-place
obj.forEach(function (item) {
    item.key2 = item.key2.toLowerCase()
})
```

or

```
var mapped = obj.map(function (item) {
    return Object.assign(item, { key2: item.key2.toLowerCase() });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to loop through the array and lowercase the value of `key2` for every object.

```
var objects = [{key1: "Value1", key2: "VALUE2"},{key1: "Value1", key2: "VALUE2"}]; 

for(var i = 0;i < objects.length;++i) {
    objects[i].key2 = objects[i].key2.toLowerCase();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Concept:**

Create a function to lowercase an item based on the given key.
Then, iterate items and parse each item on those function.

1. Create a function to lowercase the item based on the given key:

   `function lowerObj(obj, key) { obj['' + key] = obj['' + key].toLowerCase(); return obj; }`
2. Iterate items and parse each item on those function

   `var newObj = obj.map((item) => {return lowerObj(obj, 'your_key')});`
3. So, you will get `newObj` with lower case for the item with the given key.

   **Example**

   ```js
       function lowerObj(obj, key) {
          obj['' + key] = obj['' + key].toLowerCase();
          return obj;
       }
       var obj = [{key1: 'Value01', key2: 'Value02'}, {key1: 'Value11', key2: 'Value12'}];
       var newObj = obj.map((item) => {return lowerObj(item, 'key2')});
       console.log(JSON.stringify(newObj, null, 3));
   ```

Comment: Perhaps explain the "`'' +`" part in your answer? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you had a JSON object like.

```
"params": {
    "name": "LOWERNAME"
    "phone": "1234567899"
}
```

Call your object like:

```
let user = {
    name: params.name.toLowerCase(),
    phone: params.phone
}
```

You could modify it to suit your situation!