# Convert all objects inside an array to lower case (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects that I want to convert everything inside in this array to be lowercase. Can someone help with this:

**Original:**

```
const array_pairs = [
{
    "name": "Master",
    "contract": "asxcxcx",
    "deployer": "BCCCCCC"
},
{
    "name": "Master2",
    "contract": "bcxcssDA",
    "deployer": "ttttttttTTtttttt"
}]
```

**Desired Format:**

```
const array_pairs = [
{
    "name": "master",
    "contract": "asxcxcx",
    "deployer": "bcccccc"
},
{
    "name": "master2",
    "contract": "bcxcssda",
    "deployer": "tttttttttttttttt"
}]
```

Comment: Please review [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mre] showing your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: A very simple and slightly unorthodox solution would be to use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array_pairs).toLowerCase())`. This will work as long as it's fine that your object _keys_ also get lower-cased (in your example there were no upper-case characters in the keys so I guess it's OK).

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't clear. I went through stack overflow for a similar issue but couldn't find the right solution to my problem and got stuck for quite a while before I decided to post the question here. but this JSON method is perfect. thanks so much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lowercase JavaScript object values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39972132/lowercase-javascript-object-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const array_pairs = [
{
    "name": "Master",
    "contract": "asxcxcx",
    "deployer": "BCCCCCC"
},
{
    "name": "Master2",
    "contract": "bcxcssDA",
    "deployer": "ttttttttTTtttttt"
}];
const tempArray = array_pairs.map((obj)=>{
    const tempObj={}
  for (let key in obj){
    tempObj[key]=obj[key].toLowerCase();
  }
    return tempObj
});
console.log(tempArray)
```